# How to place NULLs last in ascending order

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-order-by

I need to sort a table and I need to display the rows that include Nulls at the bottom. Whenever I run the below query

```
select * from t1 
order by status, date;
```

Nulls show up in the first row which I don't want:

```
+--------+------------+--+

| Status |    Date    |  |
+--------+------------+--+
|      1 | NULL       |  |
|      1 | 2011-12-01 |  |
|      1 | 2011-12-21 |  |
|      2 | NULL       |  |
|      2 | 2005-09-02 |  |
|      3 | 2000-08-07 |  |
|        |            |  |
+--------+------------+--+
```

This is what I need:

```
+--------+------------+--+
| Status |    Date    |  |
+--------+------------+--+
|      1 | 2011-12-01 |  |
|      1 | 2011-12-21 |  |
|      1 | NULL       |  |
|      2 | 2005-09-02 |  |
|      2 | NULL       |  |
|      3 | 2000-08-07 |  |
|        |            |  |
+--------+------------+--+
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from t1 
order by status, 
         date, 
         CASE WHEN date is NULL 
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END;
```

Comment: Generally, this is the right answer but I need to keep the nulls or some kind of empty values because numbers will affect the results of statistical analysis.

Comment: Add another column for the date itself perhaps? edit: The date column is already in the query so I don't see the issue. Have an upvote!

Comment: I dont understand the comment. I dont remove any null only order it using the case. And this solve the example you provide in your question

Answer (score -1):

Would this work: `order by col asc nulls last`?

Comment: sql server doesnt support nulls last